# Assigning optimal jobs to entities based on travel distance

Tags: jobs, planning

*I'm hoping there is a standard algorithm for this problem, but I don't even know what to search for.*

Let's say you have a collection of entities (people, vehicles, whatever), in random locations. And you have a collection of jobs to be done, also in random locations. How do you assign each one a job where they have the least distance to travel?

- For example, several entities may have the same travel distance to job A, but only a few of those are closer to job B, making them less of a candidate for job A.
- Or, entity 1 is currently headed to job A, but entity 2 just spawned and they're even closer to job A, so entity 1 should switch to job B since they are closer to it than entity 2 is.

Seems like a lot to untangle, where would I start in structuring this?

Comment: This sounds like [the Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Here your cost for each assignment is the travel distance between the agent and the job site. You just need to include multiple copies of any job that can accept multiple workers.

Comment: It's also possible to solve this as a [transshipment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transshipment_problem) - it requires m × n edges, so scale is a concern, but as I recall, we handled problems in the low 100s in near-real time using integer programming.